# Locking a file on a shared drive for editing by only one person at a time

Tags: windows, file-sharing

A shared file exists to a number of Windows 7/8 PCs on a mapped network drive like so:

`G:\plan.xlsx`

How can one lock or control the file so as it is only editable by one person at a time?

Conflicts are extremely cumbersome to resolve, and there are not notifications when it is currently being edited.

Comment: Only relates to Excel files?

Answer (score 1):

By default, workbooks are only allowed to be edited by one at a time unless you've enabled sharing on it.

To check if sharing is enabled, go to the `Review` tab, click `Share Workbook` and uncheck `Allow changes by more than one user at the same time`.

[image]

Should anyone open the workbook without sharing enabled, they will be prompted that the workbook is in use by *{username}* and they will only be allowed the data as read only.